# Ploting horizontal lines in a ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting, grid-lines

Hello i have made a graph with a oscillating behavior but i need to highlight the maximum value of the oscillation because i will use that value like a threshold and I need to put a horizontal line in that particular spot of the graph. So for example, let say that i have the next data:

```
data = Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 0, 4 Pi, Pi/100}]
```

Then I plot the data with the next command:

```
 ListLinePlot[data]
```

And I get the next graph:

[image]

So i need to put an horizontal line in the y= 1 coordinate because that's the max value of the curves, how can i do that?

Answer (score 7):

The answer, funnily enough, is in one of your tags:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 0, 4 Pi, Pi/100}], GridLines -> {None, {1}},
             GridLinesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3/2], ColorData[97, 2]],
             Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}]
```

[image: sine and line]

---

It's always nice to have alternatives:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 0, 4 Pi, Pi/100}], 
             Epilog -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], ColorData[97, 2]], 
                        InfiniteLine[{0, 1}, {1, 0}]}]
```

Comment: ColorData[97, 2]] Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}
I think there should be a "," before 'Method'.

Comment: well-spotted, thank you @Porey!

Answer (score 2):

```
ListLinePlot[data, Epilog -> Line[{{0, 1}, {4 Pi, 1}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: For this problem 1 is the right number. I think you want to generalize it and maybe use `Max[data[[All,2]]]`, possibly defined using `With` so you don't compute it twice.